# Convert a column to rows.. complicated stuff for me.. just a beginner

Tags: php, mysql, select, pivot

This is my table in/out

```
emp_id    td_id    status     timestamp          remarks
  35        1        in   2013-12-19 10:15:09     late
  35        2        out  2013-12-19 12:00:23     example
  36        3        in   2013-12-19 10:15:09    
  36        4        out  2013-12-19 12:00:23     example
```

How can I make the select query like this

```
emp_id   status     timestamp        status     timestamp          remarks
  35       in   2013-12-19 10:15:09   out  2013-12-19 12:00:23  late, example
  36       in   2013-12-19 10:15:09   out  2013-12-19 12:00:23      example
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afe72/1/0) <----- the existing code ( 3 pairs of in/out i have. ) :) how can I add the remarks on this 3 pairs of in and out?...

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT`. I tried to add it to your fiddle, but there's no remarks column in the input table.

Comment: how will i add the group_concat in my existing code sir?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'm having trouble understanding your original SQL, it doesn't use the usual idiom for pivoting in MySQL, which uses `GROUP BY` to produce each row.

Comment: PLEASE HELP.. THE ANSWER BELOW MEETS THE 1 PAIR.. BUT I NEED 3 PAIRS OF IN/OUT... :(

Comment: I would do it in an application language rather than in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d27a34/5/0)

```
SELECT rec1.emp_id,rec1.status as status1,rec1.timestamp as timestamp1,
                   rec2.status as status2,rec2.timestamp as timestamp2,
       CASE WHEN IFNULL(rec1.remarks,'') = '' THEN IFNULL(rec2.remarks,'')
            WHEN IFNULL(rec2.remarks,'') = '' THEN IFNULL(rec1.remarks,'')
            ELSE CONCAT(IFNULL(rec1.remarks,''),',',IFNULL(rec2.remarks,''))
       END as remarks
FROM
    (SELECT emp_id,timestamp as timestampin,
           (SELECT MIN(timestamp)
            FROM overallrec t2
            WHERE t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
              AND status = 'out'
            )as timestampout
    FROM overallrec t1
    WHERE status = 'in')InOutTime
LEFT JOIN overallrec rec1 ON (InOutTime.timestampin = rec1.timestamp
                              AND rec1.status = 'in'
                              AND rec1.emp_id = InOutTime.emp_id)
LEFT JOIN overallrec rec2 ON (InOutTime.timestampout = rec2.timestamp
                              AND rec2.status = 'out'
                              AND rec2.emp_id = InOutTime.emp_id)
```

To have 3 pairs I use your existing 3 pairs code and LEFT JOIN it with T5, GROUP_CONCAT group by emp_id,formattedDate. check this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d86c8/4/0)

Comment: how could I add this in a 3 pairs of in/out sir tin?

Comment: @user3114385, check the sqlFiddle at the very end of my answer and let me know if that's what you want.